# Modifying border of circle CSS

Tags: css

It's pretty explanatory in the codepen.  The part that is square I would like removed, I tried transparency and other things but I couldn't get it to work.

How can you adjust the angle of a circle or clip a certain piece of it? My current CSS code is this

```
.circle {
   -moz-border-radius: 50px/50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 90px 0px 90px 90px;
    border: solid 25px#396bb3;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;  
  }
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rHIBg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/LsC7b/

```
.circle {
  -moz-border-radius: 90px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  border: solid 25px#396bb3;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;  
  border-top-color:transparent;

  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Equal border radius on all sides should

```
border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iohKA

Update:

```
border-top-color: #fff;
border-right-color: #fff;
transform:rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjhuF

Comment: That makes the circle, I don't need a circle.  I need somewhat of a C shape.  I need that square missing.